# Select column where header matches X and define name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set up a bit of code to select the column in my workbook where the Column Header matches "Start Date" and declare this as a named range for use in formulae.

I have tried several ways - I can currently search header row for matching cell using Selection.Find, and then ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select, but I am struggling to convert this to naming it as a range since the code from the macro recorder refers to a column letter.

Can/should I set a variable comprised of two distinct actions (Find then Select)? Or is there a simpler and cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Always best to include the code you're working with in your post.  `Find()` returns a range object (or Nothing if no match) and you can use the `Address` property to get the address of the found cell.

Comment: I'm on mobile unfortunately, all the code is on a work computer and not able to log in to SO on that. Do you know if there is a way to set my SelRange (Dim as Range) to Find + Select column?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! (Sorry for formatting, on mobile)

```
Rows("1:1").Find(What:=" Start Date", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
       xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
       xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Start_Date", RefersTo:=Selection
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("Start_Date").Comment = ""
```

I'm still new to VBA so working on not having Select, but this is a start. Any improvements welcome.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding `Select`:

```vb
Dim f As Range, ws As Worksheet, nm As Name

Set ws = Activesheet

Set f = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:=" Start Date", _
         LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart, _
         MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
'make sure you got a match
If Not f Is Nothing Then
    Set nm = ws.Parent.Names.Add(Name:="Start_Date", RefersTo:=f.EntireColumn)
    nm.Comment = ""
else
    Msgbox "Header not found!"
end if
```

edit:

```vb
Dim c as range, rng as range

for each c in activesheet.usedrange.rows(1).cells
    if c.value like "*CHECK*" then
        If rng is nothing then
            Set rng = c
        else
            set rng = application.union(rng, c)
        end if
    end if
next c

if not rng is nothing then
    'create a Name using `rng`
end if
```

Comment: Ooph that is crisp, thank you! Should nm be declared as anything?

Comment: No, clearly not, that runs beautifully. Could this be adapted to select all column headers containing *?

Comment: `As Name` I just looked it up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.names.add  Not sure what you mean by all headers containing `*`  A literal asterisk?

Comment: I mean selecting all columns with value (e.g. "CHECK") in the header, and then declaring those as a single named range. I can set it up based on column references but would love one that can run in any spreadsheet regardless of size or column position.